# Is calling not thread-safe method properly possible?

Tags: c#, multithreading, for-loop

I need to parallelize this code in C#. `listTipoGraficos` is a ListView object (I'm locking its access) but the method `this.claseChartPadre.CargarGrafico` is not thread-safe. It only modifies the input `graficos[i]` but it has very much local variables, so modify it is an horror... Can I do anything without adapting it?

```
System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<int, Grafico> graficos = new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<int,Grafico>();
for (int i = 0; i < listTipoGraficos.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
   graficos[i] = (Grafico)listTipoGraficos.CheckedItems[i].Tag;
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0,listTipoGraficos.CheckedItems.Count, i =>
{
   //Controlamos que no lo tenemos ya cargado
   if (graficos[i].EstaPintado == false || graficos[i].TipoFecha != fechaSelecionada || graficos[i].FechaIni != fechaIniSelec || graficos[i].FechaFin != fechaFinSelec)
   {
       graficos[i].TipoFecha = fechaSelecionada;
       graficos[i].FechaIni = fechaIniSelec;
       graficos[i].FechaFin = fechaFinSelec;
       //Resetea el contenido del grafico
       graficos[i].reiniciarContenido();
       this.claseChartPadre.CargarGrafico(graficos[i]); // A lot of local variables inside
    }
});
```

I can't post very much code because it isn't mine.

```
    public bool CargarGrafico(Grafico gf)
    {
        bool leido_ok = true;
        // Reding from DB
        ClaseComandoSql comando = new ClaseComandoSql();
        comando.NombreComando = this.procedimiento;
        comando.TipoComando = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        comando.AñadirParametro("@CodGrafico", gf.CodGrafico);
        comando.AñadirParametro("@Codigo", this.codigoObjeto);
        comando.AñadirParametro("@CodOpcion", gf.TipoFecha);
        comando.AñadirParametro("@FecInicial", gf.FechaIni);
        comando.AñadirParametro("@FecFinal", gf.FechaFin);
        System.Data.DataSet lector = comando.EjecutarLector(); // This is the operation I need to parallelize

        bool primeraPasada = true;
        bool codigoNulo = false;

        int totalLeyendas = 0;
        int totalAgrupaciones = 0;
        String LeyendaAnterior = "";
        int i = 0;
        // Calculus and formatting
    }
```

Basically the code create an sql command, executes it and formats a graph to draw it.

EDIT: I took this approach and seems that works well, but I think it's ugly. `sync` is an instance variable inside the class.

```
    public bool CargarGrafico(Grafico gf)
    {
        lock (sync)
        {
        bool leido_ok = true;
        // Reding from DB
        ClaseComandoSql comando = new ClaseComandoSql();
        comando.NombreComando = this.procedimiento;
        comando.TipoComando = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        comando.AñadirParametro("@CodGrafico", gf.CodGrafico);
        comando.AñadirParametro("@Codigo", this.codigoObjeto);
        comando.AñadirParametro("@CodOpcion", gf.TipoFecha);
        comando.AñadirParametro("@FecInicial", gf.FechaIni);
        comando.AñadirParametro("@FecFinal", gf.FechaFin);
        }
        System.Data.DataSet lector = comando.EjecutarLector(); // This is the operation I need to parallelize

        lock(sync)
        {
        bool primeraPasada = true;
        bool codigoNulo = false;

        int totalLeyendas = 0;
        int totalAgrupaciones = 0;
        String LeyendaAnterior = "";
        int i = 0;
        // Calculus and formatting
    }
```

Comment: Can you post code for method `CargarGrafico()` here ? It's difficult to say anything before seeing what is going on inside this method.

Comment: Edited, but I can't post all of it =(

Comment: The problem with `Parallel.For` is that you cannot use it when it comes to shared managed resources. It requires that all iterations can be executed independently without interacting with each other. And in your case you have to synchronize threads and this makes asynchronous (parallel) `for` loop rather synchronous one.

Comment: I know, but in fact the threads don't interact each other, only "share" some local variables. In another part of the code I solved it using `ConcurrentDictionary` datatype because I could index all it items and was my code, but in this case I can't. If the CargarGrafico method was inline I could declare local variables for Parallel.For but I can't.